# how to profile instruction types in a program?

Tags: linux, profiler

I try to figure out the relationship between IPC and number of floating point instructions.

I guess that the IPC would be low if there are many floating point instructions, because a floating point instruction takes more clock cycles.

To verify these statements, I need to profile the number of floating point instruction, number of instruction retired and number of clock cycles in a program.

I can use the "perf" to get IPC easily but number of floating point instructions.

Comment: Create a very long block of code with FP opcodes which dominate the execution time.